# prove $(\alpha + \beta )x= \alpha x+\beta x$

Tags: linear-algebra

for all $\alpha , \beta \in \Bbb R$ and all $x\in \Bbb R^n $ $(\alpha+\beta)x=\alpha x + \beta x$

How would you prove that? I appreciate any hints.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Why does it say $|x|$ in the title?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an outline, assuming vector space properties.

Let $x$ be represented as an $n$ - dimensional vector $<x_1, x_2, ..., x_n>$.

Then we have $(\alpha + \beta)x = (\alpha + \beta)<x_1, x_2, ..., x_n>$

$\implies (\alpha + \beta)x = <(\alpha + \beta)x_1, (\alpha + \beta)x_2, ..., (\alpha + \beta)x_n>$

$\implies (\alpha + \beta)x = <\alpha x_1 + \beta x_1, \alpha x_2 + \beta x_2, ..., \alpha x_n + \beta x_n>$

$\implies (\alpha + \beta)x = <\alpha x_1, \alpha x_2, ..., \alpha x_n> + <\beta x_1, \beta x_2, ..., \beta x_n>$

$\implies (\alpha + \beta)x = \alpha<x_1, x_2, ..., x_n> + \ \beta<x_1, x_2, ..., x_n>$

$\implies (\alpha + \beta)x = \alpha x + \ \beta x$